# Retrieve an observable with an array of data

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Imagine, I have an array of observables, inside this array of observables I have other arrays of ReferenceData, I want to be able to retrieve an Observable with an Array of ReferenceData arrays, I'm a bit stuck on it for a couple of days, is there any other way to do that?

```
export class ReferenceData {
  id: number;
  caption: string;

  constructor(_id: number, _caption: string) {
    this.id = _id
    this.caption = _caption
  }
}

const observables = [
 of([new ReferenceData(1, 'Test'), new ReferenceData(2, 'Test 2')]),
];

const getData = (): Observable<[ReferenceData[]]> {
 return observables.map((obs) => {
  return obs.pipe(
    map((data) => {
      return [...data]
    })
  )
 })
}
```

Return expected from getData function: `Observable<[ReferenceData[]]>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use forkJoin operator like below :-

```
forkJoin(observables).subscribe((res: ReferenceData[][]) => {
   // your logic here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getData = () => from(obs).pipe(switchMap(ob => ob), toArray()).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I'm actually not sure what he wants, so provide a simple answer first.